# Prepositions for change in quantity

Tags: prépositions

"The government aims to increase the interest rate **from** three percent **to** five percent."

"The government aims to increase the interest rate **by** two percent."

What are the prepositions for the change in quantity? Is it simply *de*, *à*, and *par*?

> Le gouvernement vise à augmenter le taux d'intérêt **de** trois pour cent **à** cinq pour cent.
>
> Le gouvernement vise à augmenter le taux d'intérêt **par** deux pour cent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply **de**:

> Le gouvernement vise à augmenter le taux d'intérêt **de** deux pour cent.

Comment: @user11550:The first sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"*De*" is used for exact increase, while "*par*" is used for multiplications or divisions :

> Le gouvernement vise à augmenter le taux d'intérêt **de** trois pour cent
>
> Le président veut mutliplier son salaire **par** deux

Can you tell me if you read the second sentence somewhere ? It doesn't feel correct but I may be wrong.

You also mentioned "*de ... à*", it doesn't change much. **à**  is added to give an interval, but can also be used with **par**.

> En utilisant des tracteurs plutôt que des animaux, les agriculteurs ont multiplié leur production annuelle par trois à quatre.