# Translation of "increase from .. to .."

Tags: traduction, prépositions

"The interest rate is expected to increase from three percent to five percent next month."

Is the correct translation the following?

> On prévoit que le taux d'intêret augmentera **de** trois pour cent **à** cinq pour cent le mois prochain.

Note that the meaning is that three percent is the interest rate **now**, and five percent is the interest rate **after the change**. The interpretation is *not* that the interest rate will increase between 3-5%. This seems to have created a confusion in [my last post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23107/prepositions-for-change-in-quantity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to avoid the ambiguity:

> On prévoit que le taux d’intérêt passera de trois à cinq pour cent le mois prochain.

Comment: What about if we want to use *augmenter*? Can we still do it?

Comment: Yes, *…le taux d'intérêt augmentera, passant de trois à cinq pour cent…*

Comment: If I just say "... augmentera de trois à cinq pour cent", does it work? Can it be interpreted both ways?

Comment: Your sentence might mean "it will increase from a value lying between two and five percent". You'd rather say *le taux d'intérêt actuellement de trois pour cent augmentera de deux pour cent le mois prochain.*

Answer (score 0):

A language-agnostic way to remove the ambiguity is to use points instead of percentage.

> Le taux d'intérêt devrait gagner deux points le mois prochain.

You can also replace `gagner` with `augmenter de`, `grimper`, `prendre`, and so on.

If you don't want to use points, you must make sure to avoid the `De X à Y` idiom, because it's ambiguous in this context. It can mean both "from X to Y" and "In the range [X; Y]".

I suggest the following alternative:

> Le taux d'intérêt, actuellement de 3%, devrait monter à 5% le mois prochain.